# Coding in Dart/Flutter need my first Tile to only appear one time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an app that shows local weather forecasts. I am trying to make my first tile with the most recent weather stand out and be larger and only appear one time. Currently that tile is repeating itself please help. The Sized Box is the code that is repeating and I only want that to occur once.

```
                 : Expanded(
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      // shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      itemCount: model.dailyForecast.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                        return Container(
                          child: Column(
                          children:<Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                               child: Text(
                                  "${model.dailyForecast[0].dayAndHour} " +
                                      "${model.dailyForecast[0].description}" + "loaded"),
                            ),
                            const Divider(),
                            ListTile(
                                  leading: Image.network(
                              model.dailyForecast[index + 1].iconURL),
                          title: Text(
                              "${model.dailyForecast[index + 1].dayAndHour} " +
                                  "${model.dailyForecast[index + 1].description}"),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            "Low: " +
                                "${model.dailyForecast[index + 1].minTemp} " +
                                "High: " +
                                "${model.dailyForecast[index + 1].maxTemp} " +
                                "Humidity: " +
                                "${model.dailyForecast[index + 1].humidity}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blue),
                          ),
                          ),
                          ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          const Divider(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a check on the `index` value.

```
if (index == 0) // <-- Add this condition so it appears only once.
SizedBox(
      child: Text(
      "${model.dailyForecast[0].dayAndHour} " +
      "${model.dailyForecast[0].description}" + "loaded"),
)
```